# JSON User Registration Using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I want to register a user using retrofit in android but I am not able to do it also doesn't give me any errors my user models:

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;
@SerializedName("password_confirmation")
@Expose
private String passwordConfirmation;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private String image;
@SerializedName("phone")
@Expose
private String phone;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private String address;
@SerializedName("username")

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getPasswordConfirmation() {
    return passwordConfirmation;
}

public void setPasswordConfirmation(String passwordConfirmation) {
    this.passwordConfirmation = passwordConfirmation;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
```

**Api Interface:
   @POST("/api/users/signup")
    Call signMeUp(@Body User user);**

```
public class ApiClient {

public static final String BASE_URL = "https://basobaasapp.herokuapp.com/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    return retrofit;
}
ApiInterface apiInterface=retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);


}
```

**MainActivity Code :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText et_name, et_address,et_phone,et_username,et_email,et_password,et_confipassword;
private Button register;
private User user=new User();
private ApiInterface apiInterface;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et_name=findViewById(R.id.edit_text_name);
    et_address=findViewById(R.id.edit_text_address);
    et_phone=findViewById(R.id.edit_text_phonenumber);
    et_username=findViewById(R.id.edit_text_username);
    et_email=findViewById(R.id.edit_text_email);
    et_password=findViewById(R.id.edit_text_password);
    et_confipassword=findViewById(R.id.edit_text_confirm_password);



}
public void Signup(){

    user.setName(et_name.getText().toString());
    user.setAddress(et_address.getText().toString());
    user.setPhone(et_phone.getText().toString());
    user.setUsername(et_username.getText().toString());
    user.setEmail(et_email.getText().toString());
    user.setPassword(et_password.getText().toString());
    user.setPasswordConfirmation(et_confipassword.getText().toString());


    apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> call1 = apiInterface.signMeUp(user);
    call1.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                Log.e("SignupFragment", jsonObject.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sucessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


public void Register(View view) {
    Signup();
}
}
```

I want to register a user with the following fields on the server but I am not able to do so please help me solve my problems

Answer (score 0):

What is your ResponseBody class, retrofit gets you the result in the form of ResponseBody pojo class. So the response you get when you hit the api with User as @Body should be matched to the ResponseBody pojo class. Then you can check using

> Log.e("SignupFragment", response.body());

Comment: it keeps giving me this error  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.asterdio.signup.User.setName(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: You have left the username variable declaration below @SerializedName("username")  other than that, it shouldn't give you that null object reference error.

Answer (score 0):

There is two problem with your code as I understand:

1- `@SerializedName("username")` that you didn't set it any variable, you have to do that like this:

```
@SerializedName("username")
private String address;
```

And because of this mistake, you will have a `null` object in your code.

2- When you are using retrofit and serialized model you don't need to work with JSON Objects instead of that you can work with your user model in response.

Hope it helps.